# Filtering for an Array with three inputs. Input undefined if key is empty

Tags: javascript

```
function getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, key, index) {
  var newStr = obj[key][index];

  if(!obj[key]  || !Array.isArray(obj[key]) || obj[key] === undefined)  {
    return undefined;
  } 

 
  return newStr;
}

var obj = {
 key: ['Jamil', 'Albrey']
};
var output = getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'key', 0);
console.log(output); // --> 'Jamil'

/*

getElementOfArrayProperty
    ✓ should return the element at the index of the array at the key of the passed in object
    ✓ should return undefined if the index is out of range
    ✓ should return undefined if the property at the key is not an array
    1) should return undefined if there is no property at the key

*/
```

Cannot wrap my head around why this exercise is saying "should return undefined if there is no property at the key." (!obj[key]) and (obj[key] === undefined) statements should take care of that right? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is ordering. Your function will error at the first line if obj[key] is undefined.

```
function getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, key, index) {
  if(!obj[key]  || !Array.isArray(obj[key]))  {
    return undefined;
  } 
  return obj[key][index];
}
```

Comment: so because key is undefined !obj[key] will error out the program. How do I remedy that? if(key === undefined) doesn't work. I'm thoroughly confused at this point

Comment: Look what happens at this line: `var newStr = obj[key][index];` if obj[key] is undefined. You are asking for the value of undefined[index], which will cause javascript to error. Your checks need to come *before* you attempt to get the value.

Comment: omg i'm so dumb. For some reason I was thinking my checks were causing the error out. Nope I needed to bring down my variable declaration. stupid stupid